# Generalisation of IMO 1990/P3:For which $b $ do there exist infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $n^2$ divides $b^n+1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> For which positive integers $b > 2$ do there exist infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $n^2$ divides $b^n+1$?

It was from my LTE/ Zsigmondy handout.

By taking examples, it looks like for $b= 2^k-1 , 2$ it's not true .

Here's my progress:

- I got $b=4,5,6,8,9$ works ( $2,3,7$ doesn't )
- $n$ is odd : If not then $4\mid b^n-1$ , but $b^n \equiv 0,1 \mod 4$
- If $b+1$ is a power of $2$ and $n^2\mid b^n+1$, then $n=1$ : Let $p$ smallest prime dividing $n$ ( note that it can't be $2$) . Then $n^2\mid b^{2n}-1 \implies p\mid b^{2n}-1 \implies p\mid b^{\gcd(2n,p-1)}-1 \implies p\mid b^2-1\implies p|b-1 \text{(since $b+1$ is power of $2$)}\implies p\mid b^n+1 \implies p|2.$ Contradiction.

Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Pretty famous problem!

As you have already showed that numbers of the form $2^k-1$ are not a validate candidate, we consider the case when $b+1$ is not a power of $2$.

> If $b+1$ is not a power of $2$, then there exists an odd prime divisor $p$ of $b+1$.

> Can you show Also, $p^2\mid b^p+1$ (LTE?)

> By Zsigmondy's theorem, there exists a primitive prime divisor $q$ of $b^p+1$.

> $p\neq q$

> Can you show $q^2\mid (b^p)^q+1$? (LTE again)

> So we get $(pq)^2\mid b^{pq}+1$ and thus, similarly moving ahead, we create an infinite family of $n$'s such that $n^2|b^n+1$.

PS: Woah! Amazing proof for the case when $b+1$ is a power of $2$! Like thinking about the least prime dividing $n$ was amazing :O

Comment: OMG.. this part was actually easy *shocked* after the LTE part!! I couldn't think of the LTE part , so was stuck , really nice one. 

and for b+1 power of 2 case, I g it's quite natural to take least prime ? cause that's what we do in most of exponents problem :)

Comment: @SunainaPati The insight of using LTE was like we are finding $n$'s such that $n^2|b^n+1$ so ofc it would be beneficial to work with case when $n$ is prime and to study the power distribution in $b^p+1$, its obvious to think of LTE to get a lower bound on $v_p(b^p+1)$ and surprisingly it turns out to be $2$. Stuffs after that are repetition of what was done in n=prime case. Like just replacing b by $b^p$ and searching for prime divisor of the new $B+1$ (B=b^p). 
Anyway, I didn't know that taking least primes in exponent problems is a good strategy, so thanks! Learned something new  :::::&

Answer (score 1):

We can construct b, we want:

$b^n+1\equiv 0 \mod (n^2)$

If $b=t.n^2-1$ and $n =2k+1$ is odd, then we have:

$(t.n^2-1)^n+1=M(n^2)-1+1=M(n^2)\equiv 0 \ mod (n^2)$

Where $M(n)$ is a multiple of $n^2$.

The condition is that n must be odd.